# What do these symbols mean from a programming standpoint?

Tags: c, assembly, linker, nm

I have to create a C file that when compiled, returns symbol output from `nm` with the types **A**, **B**, and **V**. I have read the man page for `nm` and searched online, but neither is helping me figure out how symbols with those types are created. What do those symbols mean from a programming standpoint? Also are there any good references I should be looking at?

Comment: Sounds like homework?

Comment: The manpage is pretty clear about what they are, but explaining the concepts is a pretty huge topic.

Comment: Didn't we have this question just a few weeks ago?

Comment: It is homework, however this is extra credit, and I'm not looking for someone to do it for me. I just need guidance because we aren't provided any.

Answer (score 2):

Of those 3, I think you can only create `B` using standard C code. That would simply be a global variable initialized to zero, ie. `int foo = 0;`. To create absolute or weak objects, you have to use compiler-specific extensions.

A weak symbol using gcc can be declared as: `int bar __attribute__ ((weak));`

I can't think of a way to declare an absolute symbol right now.

Comment: It is sort of easy to create an absolute symbol via linker script. C doesn't have such resources.